# Terraform dynamic group creation

Tags: loops, dynamic, terraform

In my below terraform code I am trying to assign groups to the instances. But for the instances test1, test2 i am able to assign groups app1, app2, app3. But I want to assign groups app1,app2,app3 to test1 instance, groups t1,t2,t3 to test2 instance. Is there any logic that I am missing in the group_assignments block. Thanks.

```
locals {
  instances = [
    {
      instance  = "test1"
      baseUrl   = "url"
      subDomain = "sd"
      groups = [
        "app1",
        "app2",
        "app3",
      ]
},
    {
      instance  = "test2"
      baseUrl   = "url2"
      subDomain = "sd2"
      groups = [
        "t1",
        "t2",
        "t3",
      ]
},
  ]
}
resource "og" "press" {
  for_each = { for k, instance in flatten(local.instances[*].groups) : k => instance }
  name     = each.value
}
resource "ol" "press2" {
  for_each                   = { for k, instance in local.instances : k => instance }
  label                      = "press-${each.value.instance}"
  preconfigured_app          = "press"
}
resource "oag" "assignment" {
  for_each = { for k, instance in local.instances : k => instance }
  app_id   = ol.press2[each.key].id
  dynamic "group" {
    for_each = each.value.groups
    content {
      id = og.press[group.value].id
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
resource "okta_group" "press" {
  for_each = toset(flatten(local.instances[*].groups))
  name     = each.value
}
```

This way you can refer to individual instances of `okta_group`, as `okta_group.press["app1"], okta_group.press["t1"]` and so on.

Comment: @Nikhilbrusli Sorry, but its not clear what you want. What does it mean "make this dynamic"? You are using dynamic blocks, there is nothing else for "dynamic" block creation.

Comment: @Nikhilbrusli I already explained in my answer what you should do. Did you try that?

Comment: @Nikhilbrusli There shouldn't be needed. Just try and post error if you get any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238649/discussion-between-nikhil-brusli-and-marcin).